# Need help in passing checkbox value and its status to jquery function

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I've a checkbox as mentioned below.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
         <input type='checkbox' name='testing1' value='testing1' onclick='javascript: testingFunction(this.checked,'testing1');'>
    </td>
    <td>
         <input type='text' name='tesing1_qty' id='testing1_qty' class='inputtext' readonly=''>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to enable the textbox once the checkbox is selected.

I've used a function as below.

```
function testingFunction(checkboxStatus,checkboxValue){ 
     if(checkboxStatus==true){ 
           $("#"+checkboxValue+"_qty").attr('readonly', false);
     }
}
```

But i'm getting a syntax error. I'm not sure where I go wrong.
Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what does the syntax error say?

Comment: This is the error    SyntaxError: syntax error
[Break On This Error]  

javascript: testingFunction(this.checked,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is your onclick, you are using all single quotes

```
onclick='javascript: testingFunction(this.checked,'testing1');'
```

change one of the sets to double quotes

```
onclick="javascript: testingFunction(this.checked,'testing1');">
```

I would change other stuff too since you tag this as jquery but I will leave this as is to solve your syntax error

Answer (score 0):

Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Rdpmj/2/) what you're trying to do?

```
$('#testing1').click(function() {
  $("#testing1_qty").attr('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

I used jquery for this, as you tagged this post as jquery..

Edit: fixed to use this.checked :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've made mistake in quotes.

Comment: np; we all have our days with string interpolation